# Manipulating a (non-root) password in Fedora 22

Tags: password

My Fedora 22 (workstation-gnome) home pc has two accounts:  steve, which has no password, and root which does have a password.  On this website, the

```
fedora 22 - change from gnome to kde4
```

topic may have reached an impasse.  It seems that the Gnome to KDE desktop is user specific; its manipulation apparently requires that the user ID have a password, at least temporarily.

I believe that I can resolve this by:

1. logging in as root
2. setting a password for the steve account
3. logging in as steve, with the password, simultaenously changing the steve account to kde
4. logging back in as root and eliminating the password from the steve account.

How do I do #'s 2 and 4 above?  After #4, I will want the steve account to have *no* password.

Answer (score 2):

Use the passwd utility.

```
# passwd steve
```

To remove the password:

```
# passwd steve -d
```

Comment: Nathan's suggestion works, and the issue raised by the following topic, on this website is now resolved:  fedora 22 - change from gnome to kde4